# How to show that the fundamental group of a based space is trivial.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Is there a sort of general method of proving that the fundamental group of a based space is trivial? I am trying to understand how to prove that a space is simply connected and I am not 100% sure of the definition of a *trivial* fundamental group.

Edit: Here is an example where you need to find show that the fundamental group is trivial:

> A subspace $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ is said to be star-shaped if there is a point $x_0 ∈ X$ such that, for each $x ∈ X$, the line segment from $x_0$ to $x$ lies in $X$. Prove that star-shaped sets are simply-connected.

Comment: There is probably no general method, but if you post a specific question here we can probably help. This isn't a very good question as it stands. A (fundamental) group is *trivial* if it only contains the identity element, or equivalently if every loop is homotopy equivalent to a point.

Comment: Sorry! I have added an example question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to show that every loop based at $x_{0}$ is homotopic to the identity. Thinking geometrically, given a loop in a star-shaped space we can pull all of the points on the loop back along the lines connecting them to the identity and still have a loop at each stage. In a bit more detail, define a function $f(x, t) = (1-t)x + tx_{0}$ for $t \in [0, 1]$ (this is the sliding along the connecting lines map). Now if $\gamma(s)$, where $s \in [0,1]$, is a loop in your star-shaped space then $H(s,t) = f(\gamma(s), t)$ is a homotopy through loops in your space to the identity loop. The space being star shaped ensures that $(1-t)x + tx_{0}$ is in the space for each $t \in [0,1]$. Star shaped sets are a special case of [contractible spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space), which are all simply connected.