# How do I compute the fundamental group of a disk?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I need to show that $\Pi_1(D^2,x)=\{id\}$ for all $x$ in the Disk.
I somehow don't see how I can compute the fundamental group, since we only have the following definition:

> The fundamental group of $X$ with base point $x$ is $$\Pi_1(X,x)=\{\text{continuous loops based ad x}\}/\{\text{homotopies that fixes base points}\}$$
> (thats really our definition}

Since this topic is really new, I don't see where to start with such an exercise.
Could someone take some time to discuss it with me, I don't want you to give me a full solution since I don't think that this would help alot.

Thank you

Comment: The disk is contractible. There are several ways to validate this. But it's certainly convex, thus you can always build the straight line homotopy to the origin $0\in D^2$, which then shows that $D^2$ is homotopic to the constant loop at $0$. Cf. the given answer below.

Comment: hmmm I comment the answer below, but I somehow don't see why this works

Comment: All you want is to confirm that given an arbitrary loop in your disk $D^2$, you can always find some homotopy to the constant loop $$\gamma_0\colon [0,1]\to D^2,\ \gamma_0(s) = 0\quad \forall s \in [0,1]$$

Comment: ah okey and then if I look at the quotient it gets the identity? But why does @Aryman Maithani used the line? this is not a loop

Comment: I'll write down an answer providing some context.

Comment: okey thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show that the fundamental group of a based space is trivial.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360499/how-to-show-that-the-fundamental-group-of-a-based-space-is-trivial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ of a topological space $X$ is defined as the group of continuous closed curves (loops) up to homotopy, that is, given the set of all continuous closed curves in $X$, we identify those curves that are homotopic to each other (this set carries a group structure). Two curves $f,g\colon I\to X$ are homotopic if there exists some homotopy $H\colon I\times I \to X$ so that $$H(0,\cdot) = f,\quad H(1,\cdot) = g$$

Now, given a convex set $K$, you can always build the so called straight line homotopy, that is, given two paths $g,f\colon I \to K$ with the same starting- and endpoints, there exists the homotopy

\begin{align}
H\colon K\times I &\to K \\ (x,t) &\mapsto f(x) + t(g(x) - f(x)) \\ &= f(x)(1-t) + tg(x)
\end{align}

Clearly, $D^2\subset \mathbb R^2$ is convex, thus, any arbitrary closed curve will be homotopic to the constant loop at the origin.

Now if all loops in your favorite space $X$ are homotopic to the constant loop (which is the identity element in $\pi_1(X)$), then $\pi_1(X)$ is simply the trivial group, i.e., consists up to homotopy only of the trivial element, i.e. the constant loop.

**Addendum**: Observe that for path-connected spaces, $\pi(X,x_0)$ is independed of the choice of basepoint $x_0$.

Comment: Thank you, I have still some questions. It is clear that $D^2$ is convex. Now I consider an arbitrary loop $\gamma: [0,1]\rightarrow D^2$ where $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$. Then I consider the function $$H:[0,1]\times [0,1]\rightarrow D^2,\,\,\,(x,t)\mapsto \gamma(x)t+(1-t)e_0(x)$$ where $e_0(x)=0$ is the constant loop. We see that H is a homotopy, since $H(x,0)=e_0(x),\,\,\,H(x,1)=\gamma(x)\,\,\, H(1,t)=H(0,t)$ Is this correct so far?
then we know that every continuous loop based at x is homotopic to the constant loop, i.e. they are in the same equivalence class, and thus $$\Pi(D^2,x)=\{id\}$$?

Comment: If I didn't see the point with the independence of the choice of the base point $x_0$ in a path connected space, could I also consider $e_z(x)$ so the constant loop at $z$ and replace $0$ by $z$ everywhere and it would still work or wouldn't it work then?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the idea. Note that you might want to mention that, since $X$ is convex, it's path-connected and therefore $\pi(D^2,x_0)$ does not depend on the choice of $x_0$, that's why we can choose $x_0 = 0$. This is due to the fact that we can concatenate paths (this is the group operation inside $\pi_1(X)$).

Comment: You could argue that your straight line homotopy was also independend of the choice of basepoint, however, i personally find it more convenient to use that $D^2$ is path connected and thus $\pi_1(D^2,x) \cong \pi_1(D^2,0)$ for any $x\in D^2$.

Comment: could you explain this a bit more, because $D^2$ path connected means that each two points can be connected by a continous path, in our case the straight line would be enough. but then why are the two spaces isomorphic?

Comment: Well, given a closed curve $\gamma$ based at some basepoint $x_0$ and given a straight line $g$ between some arbitrary point $x_1$ and $x_0$, observe that the conjugating via $g\circ \gamma \circ g^{-1}$ yields a closed curve with basepoint $x_1$.

Comment: Observe that this defines a map $\beta_g\colon \pi_1(X,x_0)\to \pi_1(X,x_1)$ by $$[\gamma]\mapsto [g\cdot \gamma\cdot g^{-1}]$$ where $\cdot$ denotes the concatenation. To see that this is indeed an isomorphism, see Proposition 1.5 in Hatcher for example. You could also try proving it yourself, if you want.

Comment: ah okey perfect thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Fix $x_0$. Note that given any point $y$ in the disc, the line joining $x_0$ and $y$ is also completely within the disc. Using this, try to figure out a homotopy between an arbitrary loop and the constant loop at $x_0$. Think of functions like $$(s, t) \mapsto (1 - t)\sigma(s) 
+ tx_0.$$

Comment: sorry I don't see why this would be helpful and I don't see the connection to my definition, so how the definition was applied to get to this hint.

Comment: why does it work with the line, since this is not a loop based at $x$.